# HIVE table not found

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Following is a simple code that is trying to create a HIVE table::

```
import java.util.Properties                                                                                                                                            
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sqlContext.implicits._

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HIVE_Test").setMaster("local").set("spark.executor.memory","1g").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE amitesh_test(VND_ID INT,VND_NM STRING,VND_SHORT_NM STRING,VND_ADR_LN_1_TXT STRING,VND_ADR_LN_2_TXT STRING,VND_CITY_CD STRING,VND_ZIP_CD INT,LOAD_TS FLOAT,UPDT_TS FLOAT, PROMO_STTS_CD STRING, VND_STTS_CD STRING);");

sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH 'path_to/part-m-00000' INTO TABLE amitesh_test");
exit()
```

I have two queries as following::

1) Since this scala code is trying to create a table name amitesh_test, then why am I getting the error

```
17/03/15 04:34:40 ERROR ClientWrapper:
======================
HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:64 Table not found 'amitesh_test'

======================
END HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================
```

2) How the sqlContext would know which HIVE Database to use to create HIVE table?

Spark version 1.6.1, scala 2.10.5.
I am pretty sure that I am missing on many things at this point here.Please suggest.

Full StackTrace as below::

```
Using Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_77)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead is set but does not apply in client mode.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.
Loading scala_code_to_import_db_tbl_to_hive.scala...
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sqlContext.implicits._
conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@148a581e
sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@320d98f5
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@70aebcee
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: extraneous input ';' expecting EOF near '<EOF>'; line 1 pos 223
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.createPlan(HiveQl.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:40)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:135)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:202)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2.apply(Parsers.scala:890)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$$anon$1.apply(PackratParsers.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.parseSql(HiveQl.scala:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQLDialect$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(HiveContext.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQLDialect$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(HiveContext.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQLDialect.parse(HiveContext.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:113)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:135)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:202)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2.apply(Parsers.scala:890)
        at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$$anon$1.apply(PackratParsers.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DDLParser.parse(DDLParser.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parseSql(SQLContext.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.parseSql(HiveContext.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:50)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:52)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:56)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:58)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:60)
        at <init>(<console>:62)
        at .<init>(<console>:66)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:680)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at scala.reflect.io.Streamable$Chars$class.applyReader(Streamable.scala:104)
        at scala.reflect.io.File.applyReader(File.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$savingReplayStack(SparkILoop.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.savingReader(SparkILoop.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom(SparkILoop.scala:675)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:740)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withFile(SparkILoop.scala:733)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand(SparkILoop.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(SparkILoop.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(SparkILoop.scala:344)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands$LineCmd.apply(LoopCommands.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:809)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:910)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:908)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:908)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:995)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

17/03/15 04:34:40 ERROR Hive: Table amitesh_test not found: default.amitesh_test table not found
17/03/15 04:34:40 ERROR Driver: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:64 Table not found 'amitesh_test'
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:64 Table not found 'amitesh_test'
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer$TableSpec.<init>(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:769)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer$TableSpec.<init>(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.LoadSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(LoadSemanticAnalyzer.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:495)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$runHive$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:484)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runHive(ClientWrapper.scala:484)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runSqlHive(ClientWrapper.scala:474)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.runSqlHive(HiveContext.scala:605)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveNativeCommand.run(HiveNativeCommand.scala:33)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:50)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:52)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:56)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:58)
        at $line32.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:60)
        at $line32.$read.<init>(<console>:62)
        at $line32.$read$.<init>(<console>:66)
        at $line32.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line32.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
        at $line32.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line32.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:680)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at scala.reflect.io.Streamable$Chars$class.applyReader(Streamable.scala:104)
        at scala.reflect.io.File.applyReader(File.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:677)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$savingReplayStack(SparkILoop.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.savingReader(SparkILoop.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$interpretAllFrom(SparkILoop.scala:675)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:740)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withFile(SparkILoop.scala:733)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadCommand(SparkILoop.scala:739)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(SparkILoop.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$standardCommands$7.apply(SparkILoop.scala:344)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.LoopCommands$LineCmd.apply(LoopCommands.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:809)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:910)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:908)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:908)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:995)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.InvalidTableException: Table not found amitesh_test
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1070)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1057)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer$TableSpec.<init>(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:766)
        ... 105 more

17/03/15 04:34:40 ERROR ClientWrapper:
======================
HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:64 Table not found 'amitesh_test'

======================
END HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================
```

I have made some changes in my code to load the file, as the file location is in HDFS::

```
    import java.util.Properties
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HIVE_Test").setMaster("local").set("spark.executor.memory","1g").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);

    sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE amitesh_test(VND_ID INT,VND_NM STRING,VND_SHORT_NM STRING,VND_ADR_LN_1_TXT STRING,VND_ADR_LN_2_TXT STRING,VND_CITY_CD STRING,VND_ZIP_CD INT,LOAD_TS FLOAT,UPDT_TS FLOAT, PROMO_STTS_CD STRING, VND_STTS_CD STRING)");
val text_input=sc.textFile("hdfs://server-name:port/path_to/part-m-00000");
    sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://server-name:port/path_to/part-m-00000' INTO TABLE amitesh_test");
    exit()
```

I am getting error::

```
============================
17/03/15 07:14:15 ERROR ClientWrapper:

======================
HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false
OK
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10028]: Line 1:17 Path is not legal ''hdfs://server_name/path_to/part-m-00000'': Move from: hdfs://server_name:port/path_to/part-m-00000 to: hdfs://xxx.xxx.com:port/path_to/amitesh_test is not valid. Please check that values for params "default.fs.name" and "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" do not conflict.

======================
END HIVE FAILURE OUTPUT
======================
```

I have checked the "default.fs.name" in core-site.xml, and then used it in my code. So, I am sure that I didn't give the path in "LOAD INPATH" properly, that is the reason, i am seeing the error. Please correct my mistake.

Comment: Why don't you just create an external table *from Hive* over `path_to/`?

Comment: Or `sc.textFile("path_to/part-m-00000")` to a DataFrame, and save that to a table?

Comment: it will go for default database but its always best practice mention the database.

Comment: The first statement crashed ... `extraneous input ';'` And the second one therefore errored because table not created.

Comment: @Cricket_007, my main intention is to create HIVE table through scala, as per my project requirement.

Comment: I understand that, I guess, but `DataFrame.saveAsTable` works just as well.

Comment: Yes, I saw that error for extraneous input ';', and I am still wondering that where am I suppose to make the correction. I went through the code, and I do not see the place where U need to enter ";", can you suggest?

Comment: TL;DR - Are you pointing both Spark and Hive to **same metastore location**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `";"` at the end of create statement and try again.
The table is not getting created and hence the second statement is throwing table not found error.